# Error : Type 'JNIENV' could not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am new in Android NDK running the first hello JNI example. I added the jni folder and added the c file in which I'm getting error that some are not resolved.

[image: Error]

I convert project to the C/C++ also and Add the NDK in the eclipse like below

[image: NSK]

But still have red error line in cpp file which shows some could not be resolved.

Guys help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue to add the project to Native Support.

Follow this approach:-

Android Right Click on project then Android Tools then Add Native Support.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo, it should be `JNIEnv` instead of `JNIENV`. If that doesn't fix it, then there is some configuration problem in your project.

Comment: It still have issue I set the NDK in the eclipse then what other things I have to set?